# How To properly perform arithmetic operations over Two List/Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

I have `2Arrays` of doubles on Which I need to perform arithmetic operations(+,-,/,*)

```
Array1 = d1 , d2, d3, d4, d5, d6,  ,   , d9, d10
Array2 =          d3, d4,   , d6,  , d8, d9, d10
Operation = "+";
```

**Edit** 
Above Empty elements are shown just for representation of the data 
they are all stored without the empty spaces

```
Array1 = d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d9, d10
Array2 = d3, d4, d6, d8, d9, d10
```

Req Output

```
ArrayOpt = 

[0] = d3+d3

[1] = d4+d4;

[2] = d5+d4;

[3] = d6+d6;

[4] = d6+d8;

[5] = d9+d9;

[6] = d10+d10;
```

**What I have tried**

```
  int i = 0, PreviousIndex = -1;
   int SecondaryIndex = 0;

 // check if there is a gap
if (SecondaryIndex < DATES2.Length && Convert.ToInt32(d) != Convert.ToInt32(DATES2[SecondaryIndex]))
{
        // first value of index contain the index of second symbol date that matches with first symbol's first date.
        // eg: first data     => d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6
        //      2nd data      =>       d3 d4    d6
        // in the above case, the index would be the index of d3.
        index = DATES2.Select((v, j) => new { Index = j, Value = (int)v }).Where(p => p.Value == (int)d).Select(p => p.Index).ToList();
        if (index.Count > 0)
             SecondaryIndex = index[0];
        else
             SecondaryIndex = -1;
}

if(secondaryIndex != -1)
{
    CalculateData(operation, DATES1[i],DATES2[secondaryIndex]);
    PreviousIndex = secondaryIndex;
}
else
{
   CalculateData(operation, DATES1[i],DATES2[PreviousIndex]);
}

i++;
secondaryIndex++;
```

but the output is this

```
d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d9, d10
+
d3, d4, d6, d8, d9, d10
```

Can anybody suggest what is the issue or any other better solution?

Comment: So how do you represent empty or non-existent values in the double array ? for example, d1,d2 doesn't exist in second array, how do you declare them your code ? Or in other words, how do you recognize d3 is actually d3 and now the missing d1,d2 ?

Comment: d3 is a date lets say" 25 Dec 2018 " d2 and d1  are  23 and 24 DEC respectively the second list has" 25 Dec 2018" as first element

Comment: Your example is hard to follow. For example `[4] = d6 + d8` makes little sense. Make sure what you've written is correct. From what I can tell, ignoring the anomalies, your second array is a mixture of values and "holes". The holes may be at the beginning, the end, or in the middle. Since middle _holes_ are possible, you can't just use start and stop ranges. Instead, you'll need to represent each of the holes. What I'd do is make the second array a `double?[ ]` and represent the holes with `null`s. Then, just loop over the arrays in a `for` loop.

Comment: Here the combination `d6 + d8` makes sense because here there is a last used date present and doesn't apply on 22(in the first list) and 25(in the second list) is because the second  product never existed before 25 but in case of d8 (in the second list ) d6(in first list) is present as last used date... @Flydog57

Comment: Since i started, the comment about the Dates showed up. If this is your case, use two `Dictionary <DateTime, double>`. Then use a for loop (increasing by a day each iteration), and using the current day, look up the two corresponding in the two dictionaries and do the appropriate operation if on or both are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Math.Net](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/examples/examples-csharp/LinearAlgebra/MatrixArithmeticOperations.cs) library to perform basic linear algebra operations and all kinda matrix operation stuff you may wanna use. As you can see in the link basic linear algebra operation examples shown (+,*, -, /).

Also, since you matrixes are single dimentional, you can sum Array1 and Array2 indexes as shown below with a single for loop.

```
var a1 = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5}; 
var a2 = new int[7] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

var maxLength = a1.Length > a2.Length ? a1.Length : a2.Length;

var outputArray = new int[maxLength];

for(var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    if(a1.Length < i + 1)
    {
        outputArray[i] = a2[i];
        continue;
    }

    if(a2.Length < i + 1)
    {
        outputArray[i] = a1[i];
        continue;
    }

    outputArray[i] = a1[i] + a2[i];
}

Console.Write(outputArray.GetValue(6));
```